# Sequelize Single Table Query - Relation Doesnt Exist

Tags: sequelize.js

I am trying to figure out why my `findAll()` sequelize query is failing despite the SQL being generated fitting the correct syntax of the query I am looking for. Based on the error message, it looks like the issue with the table associations, but I find it weird that this would be an issue for this simple query of one table, unless the root of the problem is actually with the global Sequelize index that is syncing all of the models together. The only other table that exists, but is not being queried here is `user_accounts` related to the table being queried `users` and I wonder if it has to do with needing that association prior to running any queries.

**Error:**

```
DatabaseError [SequelizeDatabaseError]: relation "users" does not exist
```

**Query:**

```
const db = require('../models/index');
const User = db.users;

User.findAll({ 
    where: {
        email: email,
        password: password
    }
}).then(function(user){
    console.log("USER - find done")
    console.log(user)
}).catch(function(err){
    console.log("USER - error")
    console.log(err)
})
```

**index.js:**

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/sequelize.js')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(process.cwd() + '/models/')
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

**models/users.js:**

```
'use strict';
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { Model } = require('sequelize');
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const user_accounts = require('./user_accounts');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class users extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      users.hasMany(models.user_accounts)
    }
  };

  users.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.UUID,
      defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV4,
      primaryKey: true
    },
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    active: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: true
    },
    deleted: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    freezeTableName: true,
    modelName: 'users',
    omitNull: true,
    paranoid: true,
    underscored: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at',
    deletedAt: 'deleted_at',
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: async function(user){
        console.log("beforeCreate")
        console.log(user)
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(12);
        user.password = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt);
      }
    }
  });

  users.prototype.validPassword = async function(password) {
    console.log("validatePassword")
    console.log(password)
    return await bcrypt.compare(password, this.password);
  }

  return users;
};
```

Comment: And what table name in DB? `users`?

Comment: @Anatoly yes, it is `users`

Comment: Maybe an issue with different schema names for this table?

Comment: I was thinking something similar, but it uses `public` by default which should align with my DB. Is there a good way to check what schema Sequelize is querying with?

Comment: You can turn logging SQL queries and look at this incorrect query

Comment: The query uses `"users" AS "users"` so that would be the correct table to query and the query itself runs within my SQL gui so I'm not sure why it wouldn't work with the query itself. Seems like it is using `public` as the schema

Comment: Depends on if MySQL has an ability to set schemas to search in such cases and can these schemas be set for each user/connection separately (at least there is such feature in PostgreSQL).

Comment: I am using PostgrSQL, so it should set `public` by default right?

Comment: Yes, `public` is default schema

Comment: You can indicate schema for Sequelize explicitly to check if it' schema issue or not